# Laravel: Joined booking table with time table and display already booked time on a particular date

Tags: php, laravel

I am createing a booking system and have a time table[image]
Then there is a bookings table with time_id and booked date,[image]

So I want when users search a any date, I will display all the times from times table and disable the already booked time gotten from booking table.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at Laravel's relationships. You are asking for a very basic matter and might hear it form others in a more interesting manner. Also this is a broad question without any code samples for anyone to see.